# jquery show div based on select option

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a small form and I would like to display (toggle) a specific div only if a certain element is selected.

Here my code:

```
        <select name="options">
          <option value="">-Please select-</option>
          <option value="buffet">Buffet</option>
          <option value="serviced">Serviced Menu</option>
        </select>
```

Ideally the hidden div should toggle only when the option "Buffet" has been selected.

Any ideas how I can get this accomplished? Some expert advise would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Use `.change()` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$('select[name="options"]').on('change', function(){
  $('#hiddenDiv').toggle( $(this).val() == 'buffet' );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

do like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="options">
    <option value="">-Please select-</option>
    <option value="buffet">Buffet</option>
    <option value="serviced">Serviced Menu</option>
</select>

<div id="somediv">
    Lorep Ipsum
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('select[name="options"]').on('change',function(){
  if ($(this).val().trim() == "buffet") {
    $('#somediv').show();
  } else {
    $('#somediv').hide();
  }
});
```

**DEMO:**

[**Here is Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zX7BN/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $('select[name="options"]').change(function(){
     if($(this).val()=="buffet")
         $('#somediv').show();
     else
         $('#somediv').hide();
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2tG36/)**